# Radio buttons position

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to make some radio buttons appear the same way the normal buttons appear,but it seems like what I used for the normal buttons isn't working for the radio buttons.`Graduate Student` and `Phd Student` should appear under the `Add new student` but they appear as below,how can I make them a single nice column?

[image: Menu]

```
public class Menu extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    static JPanel p =new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
public static void Butty(){
            JButton bAdd, bDelete;
            bAdd= new JButton("Add a new student");
            bAdd.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,30));
            bDelete= new JButton("Delete till geek");
            bDelete.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,30));

            JRadioButtonMenuItem jAdd1,jAdd2,jAdd3;
            ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
            jAdd2= new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Graduate Student");
            jAdd2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,30));
            group.add(jAdd2);

            jAdd3= new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Phd Student");
            jAdd3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,30));
            group.add(jAdd3);
            p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            p.add(bAdd,gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;

            p.add(jAdd2);
            gbc.gridy++;
            p.add(jAdd3);
            gbc.gridy++;


            p.add(bDelete,gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
}
    private static  void createAndShowGUI() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Something");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JPanel cp2=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                JPanel main=new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
                cp2.setOpaque(true);
                Butty();
                cp2.add(p);
                main.add(cp2);
                frame.setContentPane(main);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
        }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you guys still use Swing, why not JavaFx ?

Comment: @rokonoid Because our teacher only told us about Swing and his examples used swing.

Comment: @rokonoid  Delving into Swing threads with advice to use Java-FX is a few years premature, IMO.  Please stop it! In return, I won't try to encourage every person that asks a Java-FX question from giving up this 'flavor of the minute' technology that has not yet even made it into the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) or the main [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).  Agreed?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well, its alright! but javafx probably the talk of time now as oracle is pushing it. 
But hey, I ask you, why not try a new stuff. I loved javafx more than swing.

Comment: @rokonoid  *"javafx probably the talk of time now as oracle is pushing it"*  Define 'pushing it'.  Don't get me wrong, I've seen a few Oracle Blogs claiming it is the 'next big thing', but then I also saw Sun pushing technologies just as hard that ..vanished the next month.  **My** definition of Oracle standing behind a technology is it making it into the Java Docs and Java Tutorial.  What's yours?

Comment: Well, I agree on your stand. but hey, if you follow java one 2013, you will see, there are a great many sessions that feature JavaFX. Thats why I say they are pushing. 

however, maybe they are on the way of making javadocs and tutorial. I found few http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to pass the gridbag constraints when adding the radio buttons:

```
p.add(jAdd2);
```

should be

```
p.add(jAdd2, gbc);
```